# Python 3.4 and 2.7: Cannot install numpy package for python 3.4

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu, pip, python-3.4

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and want to use python 3.4 side by side with python 2.7.

The installation of python 3.4 worked properly. However, I cannot install the numpy package for python 3 (and as a consequence I can't install scipy, pandas etc.).

Using

```
 sudo pip3 install numpy
```

spits out the following error:

```
File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 289, in check_types

"Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to "\

SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

Btw, I already have python-dev installed.

Moreover, installing numpy via

```
 sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

does not work either since I already installed numpy for python 2.7 and the installer responds that numpy is already up to date.

What can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You have not installed the Python 3 *development package*. Install `python3.4-dev`:

```
apt-get install python3.4-dev
```

The main package never includes the development headers; Debian (and by extension Ubuntu) package policy is to put those into a separate `-dev` package. To install `numpy` however, you need these files to be able to compile the extension.

Comment: For those arriving in 2015 with a similar query (as I did) need to change the above command to `apt-get install python3.5-dev`.

Comment: And to anyone in the future: adjust the command to fit your current Python version. Yes, Ubuntu will not read your mind or the calendar. :-P

Comment: or you can just use 
`apt-get install python3-dev`
and ubuntu WILL read your mind and install the correct point release for your version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @DaveLeBlanc: it depends on the Ubuntu release which version is 'current'. On 12.04 that's [Python 3.2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/python3-dev), not 3.4.

Comment: Any idea how I could fix this error in MSYS2? I tried installing mingw-w64-x86_64-python3 and I'm getting this error when I try to install numpy using pip:    

`SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel`

Comment: @AlexEastman: sorry, no experience with MingW. If `mingw-w64-x86_64-python3` is a package, look for a `-devel` or `-dev` package to install the Python headers, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Solved by incrementing the python-dev package until I hit the right one. May need to be incremented further in the future.
Poor implementation by python developers.

`sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev`

Comment: You can run `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`, and it will install the dev package corresponding to your version of python3.