# SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I try to install matplotlib,

```
sudo python2.7 setup.py install
```

after I got error like:

> SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel

How to solve this problem? Help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.4 and 2.7: Cannot install numpy package for python 3.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892810/python-3-4-and-2-7-cannot-install-numpy-package-for-python-3-4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing python-dev dependency before your stuff.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```